# How to upload large video of size may be 400MB like that video to server using retrofit Android kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

Using this code I can only upload small video which is also show corrupted if I try to download from server and play

```
   private fun uploadVideo(file: File) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val requestBody = RequestBody.create(null, file)
            val filePart = MultipartBody.Part.create(requestBody)
            uploadViewModel.uploadVideo("assam-storage-zone", "Folder1", "myFileName.mp4", filePart)

        }
    }
```

```
@HiltViewModel
class VideoUploadViewModel @Inject constructor(private val uploadApi: UploadApi) : ViewModel(){

     suspend fun uploadVideo(storageZoneName: String,
                            folderName: String,
                            fileName: String,
                            file: MultipartBody.Part) {
         try {
             val response = uploadApi.uploadVideo(storageZoneName, folderName, fileName, file)
             Log.i("response_", response.toString())
         } catch (e: Exception) {
             Log.i("response_error_", e.message.toString())
         }
    }

}
```

```
interface UploadApi {

    @Multipart
    @PUT("/{storageZoneName}/{path}/{fileName}")
    suspend fun uploadVideo(
        @Path("storageZoneName") storageZoneName: String,
        @Path("path") folderName: String,
        @Path("fileName") fileName: String,
        @Part requestBody: MultipartBody.Part
    ): ResponseBody

}
```

I am expecting that I should be able to upload larger video.

Comment: It depends on *why* it fails with larger files. Is your backend killing the upload? Or your client? Something else? Any relevant errors in your log, on either client or server side?